# Can a single regex capture group capture a phrase without some of its middle characters?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm working on an XML that lists regexs that are to be used as capture groups. Why it's done this way is a long story and not something I can change.

I've just come upon a situation where I want to capture a name that spans two lines, i.e. `Bob\nJones`. Is there any way for me to capture that whole name into one capture group *without using any other capture groups* in Perl using regex? Basically, what I want is for `$1 = "Bob Jones"`, replacing the `\n` with a space.

I'm thinking this isn't feasible and the right way would just be to use to capture group for the first and last name (which I can't do in my case), but I figured I'd ask anyway, before I give up on it. Any ideas?

Comment: why note capture the whole and do a replace `s/\n/ ` afterwards ?

Comment: I only have access to an xml full of regexs to be used as capture groups. I don't have access to do any actual Perl on them, so my options are really limited to figuring out a way to shove this name into one capture group. It's really aggravating.

Comment: You should perhaps make clear that it is a _database_ of single regexes (I understood it so), i.e. some store that keeps, for example, a key "Name", pointing to a value that is a regex string.  That this store is implemented as an XML file might be confusing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

Comment: Even if you could, you'd end up with "BobJones" since you can't do any substitution, if I understand your limitations correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should look at some of the XML parser modules. [XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~grantm/XML-Simple-2.18/lib/XML/Simple.pm) is pretty ...well... simple and can parse the XML file better than you can with just regular expressions. As you found, sooner or later, you'll get to a point where the regular expressions start to get quite convoluted as you attempt to parse each and every possible combination.

I wish the standard Perl install came with XML and HTML and LWP modules. A significant amount of my Perl scripts always need HTML access or parsing XML files, and it's sometimes not possible to download and compile modules you need from [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/). I believe XML::Simple needs a few other XML modules in order to work ([XML::SAX](http://search.cpan.org/~grantm/XML-SAX-0.96/SAX.pm) comes to mind), but there's no C code compilation.

That means you can place the XML::Simple module in the directory with your Perl script. The `@INC` array does contain the current directory by default. (Or, you can use the [use lib](http://perldoc.perl.org/lib.html) pragma).

Comment: The XML is a red herring.  The regexes are simply _stored_ in an XML file (and then presumably used by some other program).  He's not parsing the XML with regexes.